# how can i build a dynamic nodename in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

i have a xml that is converted by this script :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" indent="no" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>


<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="LogDataExport/logdata"/>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Build your output file, set date and time and then recurse the rest
of input doc -->
<xsl:template match="logdata">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:element name="Date">
                <!-- Grab the Date/Time from the first LogDataSet/t element -->
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(LogDataSet[1]/t,'T')"/>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="Time">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(LogDataSet[1]/t,'T')"/>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- For each name element in LogDataSet create an element with that value
and set the value to the content of the value element -->
<xsl:template match="LogDataSet">
    <!-- remove spaces and % symbol from name value -->
    <xsl:element name="{translate(translate(translate(name,' ',''),'%','P'),'&#252;','u')}">
        <xsl:value-of select="value"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Identity template recurse input document elements and attributes -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The Output looks like this :

```
<logdata><Date>2013-04-13</Date><Time>01:04:18.329</Time>
    <Sensor1>26.45</Sensor1>
    <Sensor2>48.24</Sensor2>
    <aquaeroCPU>33.14</aquaeroCPU>
    <Flow1>162.2</Flow1>
    <Flow2>152</Flow2>
    <Fan2>892</Fan2>
    <Fan3>900</Fan3>
    <Fan4>877</Fan4>
    <FullstandinP>80</FullstandinP>
    <Wassertemperatur>28.76</Wassertemperatur>
    <Pumpe>87.852875717465153</Pumpe>
    <Pumpe>12.147540983606557</Pumpe>
    <Pumpe>0.584</Pumpe>
    <Pumpe>5271.1725430479091</Pumpe>
  </logdata>
```

You see the last 4 Names are all the same.

how can i get a number behind the Name like:

```
<Pumpe1>
<Pumpe2>
<Pumpe3>
...
```

or is it possible to generate a name from two other names in the original xml :

```
<LogDataSet>
  <t>2013-04-13T01:08:47.751</t>
  <value>0.5696</value>
  <name>Pumpe</name>
  <unit>A</unit>
  <valueType>current</valueType>
  <device>aquastream xt</device>
</LogDataSet>

this should transformed to <Pumpe-current> aka <xsl:element name="name" - "valueType">
```

thank you

mic

Comment: What does your input data look like?

Comment: Yes, all of this is possible. Edit the question and provide a complete (but short) source XML document. Also, provide the exact wanted result. Then many people would be able to give you a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [attribute value template](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#dt-attribute-value-template). Your existing stylesheet already has one but only uses `name`. This:

```
<xsl:element name='{name}-{valueType}'><xsl:value-of select='value'/></xsl:element>
```

should give you:

```
<Pumpe-current>0.5696</Pumpe-current>
```

Comment: This omits all the `translate` operations on the value of `name` from the original XSLT

Comment: Yes; at least with this example data, they're unnecessary. You would use that current `translate` expression instead of just `{name}` to retain that behaviour.

Comment: Thanky to you all .. it was a little bit tricky for a noob like me but at the end - it works :
**<xsl:element name="{concat(translate(translate(translate(name,' ',''),'%','P'),'&#252;','u'), '_', valueType)}">**

Answer (score 0):

First of all it is convenient to put the bare name, with all the `translate` operations in place, into a variable.

```
    <xsl:variable name="element-name" select="translate(translate(translate(name,' ',''),'%','P'),'&#252;','u')"/>
```

Then, to add an index to the end of the name, just count the number of preceding `LogDataSet` elements with the same name value.

```
    <xsl:element name="{concat($element-name, 1+count(preceding::LogDataSet[name=current()/name]))}">
```

Ord to append the value of `valueType`, just use `concat`

```
    <xsl:element name="{concat($element-name, '-', valueType)}">
```

Comment: Thanky to you all .. it was a little bit tricky for a noob like me but at the end - it works :
**<xsl:element name="{concat(translate(translate(translate(name,' ',''),'%','P'),'&#252;','u'), '_', valueType)}">**